# How to zip directory while excluding files/folder in matlab

Tags: matlab, zip

I have a directory

```
C:/Simulations/Dyno
```

And `Dyno` has folders and files lets say

```
C:/Simulations/Dyno/Folder1    
C:/Simulations/Dyno/Folder2
C:/Simulations/Dyno/foo.txt
C:/Simulations/Dyno/foo2.txt
```

In Matlab how would I zip the folder `Dyno` but exclude the `folder2` and `foo.txt`?
I want `Dyno` to be a directory in the zip file and not just `folder2` and `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full path of all files and folders you want to zip, and pass them as a second argument to Matlab's [`zip`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/zip.html) function in the form of a cell array. The base folder is passed as a third argument. The resulting zip file is created in your current folder.

In your example:

```
filename = 'Dynozip'; %// name of generated zip file
list = {'Dyno\Folder1','Dyno\foo.txt'}; %// files and folders to be included
basefolder = 'C:\Simulations'; %// base folder
zip(filename, list, basefolder)
```